# iptables and port redirection (nat)

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am trying to build a router from ubuntu 12.04. What I am trying to do is, by using 1 public IP (100.0.0.100) and I tons of local ips like 10.0.0.0/16, to map each port to one ip like;

```
100.0.0.100:5678 <-> 10.0.0.5:80 // http://100.0.0.100:5678 should bring me web server on 10.0.0.5
100.0.0.100:6789 <-> 10.0.0.6:8080
100.0.0.100:7890 <-> 10.0.0.7:22
....
```

What I did is;
I build the NAT rules like below (Assuming that this accepts packets from eth0 and forward it through eth1)

```
iptables --flush
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth1 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth0 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables-save
service ufw restart
```

And then tried these commands;

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 213.128.88.2:80
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 80 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

> I Tested is by trying to open the web site with the IP 192.168.0.36 (Which is the
>   Ubuntu Server IP)

Additionally; Output of "iptables -t nat -L" is;

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http to:213.128.88.2:80

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

What I tried is to iptables with various nat rules but I cannot achieve this. How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance,
Baris

Comment: What doesn't work?  What exactly did you use for rules.  What errors do you get?  Add more details.

Comment: Zoredache, you are right, sorry for misinformation. I am now adding the new info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the NAT itself set up and working (there are about a million tutorials for that), port forwarding is just a normal rule, eg

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5678 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.5:80
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 5678 -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Lather, rinse, and repeat for every port you want to forward somewhere.

To set up the NAT itself, do something like this:

```
ifconfig eth1 10.0.0.1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

(Assuming eth1 is your local network and eth0 is your internet connection.) Then add the port forwarding commands.

Comment: Hi Bandrami, I did what you told me but it still does not work, maybe I am missing something so I added how I build the NAT itself. Thanks

Comment: Hi again Bandrami, I am trying to analyze the situation by looking at "iptraf" and with the previous configuration I was able to see ip 213.128.88.2 but with your config I cannot see it either.

Comment: Thanks Bandrami, what you did was correct, however we applied it wrong :)